# Concatenating string variable inside a for loop in the bash shell

Tags: shell-script

```
#!/bin/bash

names= find /home/devuser -name 'BI*'
echo $names

for name in {names[@]}
do    
 echo $name
 $var = $var$name   
done

echo $var
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Answer (score 29):

```
#!/bin/bash

names= find /home/devuser -name 'BI*'
echo $names

for name in {names[@]}
do    
 echo $name
 var=$var$name //$ should be removed which is prefixed before var. Blank space before and after equal sign should be removed to run this code.   
done

echo $var
```

Comment: Are you sure is correct to use sigil in front of the variable name on the left side of an assignment? Anyway, better review your entire post, starting with that comment.

Comment: Better. :) Now the comment. Then executing and capturing `find`'s output. Then the array variable in the `for`'s `in` clause.

Comment: The final point will probably be that is better to use no loop: `var="$(IFS=; echo "${names[*]}")"`. So unless you wish to teach the question owner, there is no much benefit in correcting his multiple syntax errors.

Comment: You forgot a `$`, the for loop line should read `for name in ${names[@]}`

Answer (score 7):

Change

```
$var = $var$name
```

to

```
var=$var$name
```